# How to blur image which coming from URL in eclipse?

Tags: android

I am working on app in which I want to show blur image before downloading. But I want to get the images by URL. what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what is happening in these situations is you need to request a blurred thumbnail from the server (Usually very small so it downloads quickly), and then begin the download of the full image. This is something that has to be done by the server

Answer (score 0):

Yep ,you want it like Whatsapp profilepicture? Blurred First then Download the Whole while onClikced?

To achieve that first you need to download a Thumbnail image of it,which will be very small in pixels,then display it in ImageView with `scale:fitXY`,it will be Blurred and unclear ,then Download Original Image using AsyncTask and `onPostExecute()` set the original Image into ImageView.

That Will Works Fine

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/) image library by facebook. It might come handy as it supports streaming Progressive JPEGs. From the docs,

> Fresco supports the streaming of progressive JPEG images over the
>   network.
>
> Scans of the image will be shown in the view as you download them.
>   Users will see the quality of the image start out low and gradually
>   become clearer.

you can use the below code mentioned [here](http://frescolib.org/docs/progressive-jpegs.html#_) to load your image.

```
Uri uri;
ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(uri)
    .setProgressiveRenderingEnabled(true)
    .build();
DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
    .setImageRequest(request)
    .setOldController(mSimpleDraweeView.getController())
    .build();
mSimpleDraweeView.setController(controller);
```